# Is this an arrow function declaration? Is there such a thing?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions, function-expression

I am looking into function expressions vs function declarations using arrow functions.

I am thinking this is an arrow function expression:

```
const johan = greeting = () => {
  console.log("Hi from arrow function expression");
};
```

and that this is an arrow function decleration:

```
 ludwig = () => {
  console.log("Hi from arrow function declaration");
};
```

Is that correct? Or maybe there is no such thing as an arrow function declaration?
Maybe there is only arrow function expressions?

If so, what is it called when I put a named arrow function expression in another variable?

Happy for any answer! :)

Comment: Both are the same thing. `ludwig` just happens to have been defined earlier, with `var` or `let`, or possibly none of them

Comment: Note that `const johan = greeting = 42` is also valid - it just assigns both variables the same value.

Comment: *Or maybe there is no such is as an arrow function declaration* Correct, there's no *arrow function declaration*. Arrow functions are used only in expressions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

There are function declarations, function expressions, and arrow functions (the syntax which creates them also being an expression).

(There are also [method declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) which can [use arrow functions](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2015/11/02/of-classes-and-arrow-functions-a-cautionary-tale/).)

> ```
> ludwig = () => {
>   console.log("Hi from arrow function declaration");
> };
> ```

This is assigning a value (an arrow function) to a variable.

The variable declaration is missing, so either it appeared earlier or this creates an implicit global (which is forbidden in strict mode).